# Topologically continuous functions with multi-valued inverse function

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider the inverse sine function . From basic calculus we know that it is a continuous function . However, for a given  $\ x $ $\ \epsilon $ [-1,1] ,there can be many possible values for $\sin^{-1} x$ . Similarly ,there can be a lot of such functions having more than one pre-images for any given value. Let $\ f $ be one such function . 
Now ,let  us consider the continuity of $\ f $ in a topological manner . Now , let under a given topology a  subset $\ k $ in [0,1] be open . Now if we say that $\ f $ is continuous topologically then does it mean that all the set of pre-images of $\ k $ should be open ? Like , let's say , in case of the whole set [0,1], which suppose is included in the topology, should all the sets  [0,$\ \pi \over 2 $] ,the set [2$\ \pi $,$\ 5\pi \over 2 $]...be open in $\ R $ ?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:=\sin$ is continuous when considered as a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$, but also if you consider it as a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to X:=[{-1},1]$, whereby $X$ is a topological space in its own right, having obtained its topology as a relative space of ${\mathbb R}$.

Consider the following example: The set $V:=\ \bigl]{1\over2},1\bigr]$ is open in $X$. I claim that the set $U:=f^{-1}(V)$ is open in ${\mathbb R}$. *Proof:* Consider an arbitrary point $c\in U$. Then $\sin c>{1\over2}$, hence $\delta:=\sin c-{1\over2}>0$. As $\sin$ has Lipschitz constant $1$ it follows that $|\sin x-\sin c|<\delta$ when $|x-c|<\delta$, and this implies
$$\sin x>\sin c-\delta={1\over2}$$
for all these $x$. In other words: The full $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ belongs to $U$. As $c\in U$ was arbitrary this proves that $U$ is open.

On the other hand, if you introduce on the receiving space ${\mathbb R}$ a new topology to your liking it may be that $\sin$ is no longer continuous.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called continuous if for any open set $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. An equal definition is that the inverse of any closed set is closed. Since $[0,1]$ is a closed set we must have that $\sin^{-1}([0,1])$ is closed. You can check for yourself that this is true.

Comment: Here, I am supposing that under the given topology [0,1] is open and as you can see there are more than one sets in R which can act as its inverse,so I was asking if all of these sets need to be open .

Comment: The inverse is the union of all these sets, $f^{-1}(O) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)\in O\}$.